# How to changhe the opacity of a button in Swift for an X amount of time

Tags: swift, button, opacity, alpha, ibaction

I am aware of sender.alpha being the operator (is it an operator? please correct me) to change the opacity of a pressed button on Swift but how do I add the effect to where the button becomes slightly opaque for 0.2 seconds then goes back to normal?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dispatch async After

```
button.alpha = 0.3
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) { self.button.alpha = 1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```swift
sender.layer.opacity = 0.3
```

Just experimented with brining to make opacity back to 1 but smooth (looks nice):

```swift
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
    sender.layer.opacity = 0.4
}
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.15) {
    sender.layer.opacity = 0.6
}
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) {
    sender.layer.opacity = 0.8
}
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.25) {
    sender.layer.opacity = 1
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).